# Tkinter cascade menu based on fixed argument function calls

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a cascade menu that is dynamically created once, it is meant to build a new window based on the argument received. However, it seems that using a lambda function with an argument causes the argument to be soft coded. I'd like it to remain hardcoded once the menu is created.

See this minimal working example:

```
from tkinter import *

def print_number(num):
    print(num)

root = Tk()
menubar = Menu(root)
cascade_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
for ii in range(0, 5):
    cascade_menu.add_command(label=str(ii), command=lambda: print_number(ii))

menubar.add_cascade(label="Number printer", menu=cascade_menu)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

This creates a small window with one cascade menu, with entries 0,1,2,3,4. I'd like to click "0" and have "0" being printed on the console, same for every other number. But because `ii` was left defined as 4, every command will simply print 4. This si because the command is being called with the variable `ii`, not with the value this variable had when the command was assigned, which is what I preferred.

Any workaround to this? I've tried declaring a list of lambda functions, but the problem persists. I've tried using the `eval` function but it also does not solve the issue on the real version of the problem, as apparently I need to pass another structure as an argument, which is not found when the eval is called. The alternative I'm considering is to use a script to write a big file that effectively contains declarations of functions such as:

```
def print1():
    print_number(1)
def print2():
    print_number(2)
```

And so on. But this would be very troublesome.

I'm working with python 3.7 in windows.

Comment: Force a closure by `command=lambda i=ii: print_number(i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the lambda function uses a format like `lambda x=myvar: function(x)` where the lambda function is forced to re-assign and use the variable in the function. The following code should work:

```
from tkinter import *

def print_number(num):
    print(num)

root = Tk()
menubar = Menu(root)
cascade_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
for ii in range(0, 5):
    cascade_menu.add_command(label=str(ii), command=lambda ii=ii: print_number(ii))

menubar.add_cascade(label="Number printer", menu=cascade_menu)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps!